# phalcon installed components or not coming in cmd windows opertaing system

Tags: php, frameworks, phalcon

I have installed the phalcon in windows by adding `phalcon_dll` to **xampp/php/ext** and added extension in `php.ini` file now when i checked whether it installed or not i did `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` then i can able to see that it is installed..

Now i want to create a new skelton application through **cmd** when i type phalcon it should show the components as per documentation but its sayin this:

```
C:\Users\Amerytrech-Waheed>phalcon
'phalcon' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

im tryig do like this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/phalcon/phalcon_environmental_setup.htm
but little confused **what are all need to add in system variables.?**

and what is the alternate solution to create skelton?
[image]

Comment: 3rd one today around `is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file`

Comment: i didnn't get u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 5 in the very [document](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/phalcon/phalcon_environmental_setup.htm) you pasted states:

`After downloading the package, set the path variable in the system properties`
it then explicitly shows you an image that shows the path to add, separated by a semicolon.

`;C:\phalcon-devtools-master`

So if you are unclear on where to set this.

Right click `Computer` -> `Properties` -> `Advanced` -> `Environment Variables` -> `Path` then add the path mentioned above to the very end of the path string.

Comment: what are all need to add in system variables.? @Gerhard

Comment: Just what I said, the path to the files you installed, so if you installed it in `C:\phalcon-devtools-master` then that is what path you put in.